# Setting select dropdown to be selected if value exists Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to set the select value to selected if the corresponding value exists in the database. I have used the code in multiple places within the site and on this page, but on this page some of them work and some of them do not.

this is the code:

```
<select data-rule-required='true' data-rule-required='true' name ='op_businessdriver' class="form-control">
  <option value=''>Business Driver</option>
  <% @driver.each do | dr | %>
    <option value = '<%= dr.id %>' <% if @p.op_businessdriver == dr.id %> selected='selected' <% end %>><%= dr.driver_name %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

`@p.op_businessdriver` returns a `1`, and `dr.id` returns `1,2,3,4,5`. I would expect for the first option in the select to be selected (not including the default at the top which has no value).

Don't know why this is working on some select fields but not on others.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the form helper? Are you using simple_form gem, because then you can do something like: `f.assiciation :driver`

Comment: are the types different? i.e. is one a string and one an integer? You could try adding `.to_s` or `.to_i` to **both** and see if the option becomes selected.

Comment: thanks bo-oz... will have a look at that.

Comment: thanks martincarlin87. You are spot on.... that did resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Rails helper tag. Your code is pretty messy.

**Example:**

```
<%= select_tag :business_driver, options_from_collection_for_select(@driver, "id", "driver_name", @p.op_businessdriver.id) %>
```

For more information check the [Docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) of the `select_tag`.

Comment: Thanks Tobias for this.... Its my first rails project so still finding my legs on this one. Ill have a look at the Rails helpers.

Comment: You're welcome! The [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are very good to start.